# sending an email using MAMP and php scripts

Tags: php, email, mamp

Hi I am running MAMP on my mac to locally host a website. I want to send an email using php scripts. The stuff i looked online tells me about php scripts for emails but i am unable to send emails. I am guessing this has to do with MAMP settings or maybe i have to make changes to php.ini file but i cant find information regarding that. Can i send emails to my clients using my gmail address running php scripts. I am creating a signup page where once you signup successfully, the site sents you a welcome email. Can some body please guide me how to do this. I have used code from here:
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm
but this doesnt work.
i have used following settings:
    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";

Comment: Have you tried some of these suggestions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226299/php-mail-on-mamp

Comment: Has anyone written a step by step how to? Im trying to do the same thing but I dont know much about setting up environments. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MAMP is just Apache, MySQL and PHP and doesn't include a mail server. You could use [postfix](http://jspr.tndy.me/php-mail-and-osx-leopard/) or, as you said, an external SMTP server.

If using Gmail make sure your account is setup to allow SMTP connections (it's off by default). This can be found somewhere in Settings in the web client. I'd recommend you test it with Mail or another mail client on your local machine to make sure Gmail is working as expected.

Finally (once the above is set up) [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/) are good mail libraries which can connect to remote SMTP servers. It'll save you a lot of headaches writing your own code, especially when it comes to file attachments and such.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. This explains a lot. However, im not sure which one is easier to use and whats the difference between postfix and PHPMailer. Ideally I want to avoid reading libraries.

Comment: +1 for `postfix` as it comes preinstalled on `OS X` and require almost no configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer to an old question: my MAMP is version 6.8.1, and I am on a Mac.

The MAMP `php.ini` file for my MAMP includes

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
MAMP_MailHog_MAMPsendmail_path = MAMP_mhsendmail_MAMP
```

Comment out the default mailing configuration so MailHog will be used:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25
```

1. Download and install [MailHog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog)
2. Edit `/private/etc/postfix/main.cf` to include:

```
myhostname = localhost
relayhost = [127.0.0.1]:1025
```

3. View your local email by browsing to `http://localhost:8025/`

MAMP's own documentation on this:
https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Servers-and-Services/MailHog/