# Send mail from localhost with PHP with MAMP

Tags: php, email, mamp

I've been trying everything I can find on the internet for this, and none of them seem to be working, so I'm doing something wrong and I need some help figuring out what.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = myemail@yahoo.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f myemail@yahoo.com
```

The above code is what I have changed everything to, (except for the email is my actual email (also I'm not sure if yahoo email will work with this or not, so maybe that's the problem?))
I am not sure where the sendmail_path goes to, I cannot find that path anywhere (am I suppose to download some file/program called sendmail?)

also, my APACHE port I have changed to 80, and my MySQL port is 3306, (I don't know if those ports have anything to do with the smpt_port or not)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

(if there are any other ways, (easier ways) of doing this, please also let me know).

Comment: MAMP - so you're on a mac? Probably won't have the actual sendmail, but may have postfix or exim, both of which provide a sendmail alias and masquerade as sendmail.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on a Mac, and okay I'll see about those thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending an email using MAMP and php scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727467/sending-an-email-using-mamp-and-php-scripts)

Comment: I know this post is 2 years old, but for what it's worth: the usr folder is a hidden one.

See this post to show hidden folders in Finder: http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-finder-3520878/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAMP PRO already has this, and has a simple interface to do this, I got it and I have it working perfectly.
http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/

Comment: First time I see a validated answer with negative votes o_0

Answer (score 6):

The solution on this post finally worked for me.
https://tripleroi.com/solvedenabling-sendmail-on-localhost-for-mamp-free-version/

Correct setting in php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = don@tripleroi.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path =/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f  yourname@example.com
```

You have to make sure to comment out the Win32 settings. After doing that, my MAMP server on my Mac finally got a mail through.

Comment: Link no longer works, can you provide a code example.

Comment: Get ready to get a hell of a load of emails from the past, which were all stored and never sent until you change this :).

Comment: This solution still works in July 2022 with latest Mamp 6.6 and php 8.1.1

Comment: March 2024, MAMP now includes MailHog.  I answered this question using MailHog.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have an array of problems like this including the email one when I was still using MAMP.

MAMP Pro should fix it all, but I recommend just doing an install of apache/php/mysql yourself. You'll have no more problems with basic stuff like this and it's a free solution.

If you're on OSX apache is already there, php can be installed via [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/). Mysql can just be downloaded from the official site as an installer.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly off-topic, but you should know that if you're sending emails to any sort of real customers from the localhost, they're very likely to end up in spam. Instead of using a local email server, use one of the third-party, super-cheap email sending services: Amazon SES or Sendgrid are both easy to get started with, and easy to scale up with.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in empty /etc/postafix/main.cf

```
cat /etc/postafix/main.cf
```

shows nothing. But there was not empty main.cf~orig
So I've hust copied contents from main.cf~orig:

```
sudo cp main.cf~orig main.cf
```

After that MAMP starts sending mails.

Answer (score 0):

MAMP has changed since this question was asked, and now includes [MailHog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog), which makes it much easier to test emails.

Environment:  MAMP is version 6.8.1, and I am on a Mac.

The MAMP `php.ini` file for my MAMP includes

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
MAMP_MailHog_MAMPsendmail_path = MAMP_mhsendmail_MAMP
```

Comment out the default mailing configuration so MailHog will be used:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25
```

1. Download and install [MailHog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog)
2. Edit `/private/etc/postfix/main.cf` to include:

```
myhostname = localhost
relayhost = [127.0.0.1]:1025
```

3. View your local email by browsing to `http://localhost:8025/`

MAMP's own documentation on this:
https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Servers-and-Services/MailHog/

Answer (score -5):

Set `'from'` in `mail.php` config file.

Comment: You may only send mails from emails attached to your domain... On localhost you don't have such an email