# Getting success when sending mail but not receiving

Tags: php, mamp

I tried everything I can but I'm not getting yet the mail in my inbox

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
$sql="select email from email";
foreach($conn->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $simos){
$mail=mail($simos['email'],$_POST['subject'],$_POST['msg']);
echo $simos['email'];
 if($mail){
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failed."; 
}
```

thanks for your help :)

Comment: Check your mailserver logs. It might also be blocked by the recipient's spam filters.

Comment: how can I check my mailserver logs (it's my email i'm sending it to and it's not showing even at the spam messages) @Barmar

Comment: I'm talking about the log in the machine running the script and sending the mail. It depends on what mailserver software you're running there.

Comment: I'm really sorry if I'm a pain for you, but it's my first time doing this.... So I'm not exactly sure what to do... I'm using a Mac OS Mojave , and I'm using mamp. @Barmar

Comment: I'm not sure how MAMP configures mail by default. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226299/php-mail-on-mamp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)